# Python Django Не удается получить доступ к сайту

Tags: python, django

В строке ввода браузера пишу http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ , но страница не хочется открывать. Не подскажите в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/exceptions/

Comment: Спасибо огромное